# Installing Unity3d in Ubuntu 16.04 from terminal

Tags: 16.04, unity3d

How to Install [Unity3d](https://unity3d.com/) from the terminal in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04, Unity 3d is the default desktop environment. Are you using a different Ubuntu version/desktop environment than Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Thank you for pointing this out. I should have checked the link.